# Proving a property of a peculiar polynomial

Tags: polynomials

I want to show that we can find a real polynomial $p(y)$ such that
$p\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right)  = \frac{x^n-1}{x^n}$ if and only if $n$ is an
odd positive integer.

I imagine starting with our assumption on $n$ would be the easier of the two
paths for this bidirectional proof, so I would like to start by assuming
$n$ is odd and a positive integer. I started to play around with $p$ under this
assumption about $n$:
$$p\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right) = \frac{x^n - 1}{x^n}
= \frac{(x-1)(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} x^i)}{x^n}$$
$$= \frac{x-1}{x}\frac{(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} x^i)}{x^{n-1}}.$$
It seems like the $\frac{x-1}{x}$ seems like a convenient representation, but
the second term seems difficult to morph into a function of $\frac{x-1}{x}$.
Any recommendations, as well as any suggestions on proving the other direction?

Comment: Don't know about the `only if` part. $p(x) = -x^2 + 2 x$ works for $n = 2$.

Comment: Hint: let $y = \frac{x-1}{x}$. Then $x = ...\;$ and substituting back into the equation $p(y) = ...\;$.